# Ubuntu 14.04 Dual monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I am in the process of moving from Windows XP to Ubuntu 14.04.  I need to be able to run in what windows calls 'extended desktop'.  As soon as I plug in the projector or a monitor the video output jumps to the external display and shut off the built in display.  I have tried adjusting the display settings and it still jumps and I can't get the internal display to come on until I disconnect the external device. Every time I do this the settings are changed from built in display to all displays.

Comment: What graphics card do you have? Do you use gnome-control-center monitors or the control app from a proprietary graphics card (like nvidia-settings)?

Comment: The Computer is an Acer netnook Aspire one. The graphic card is whatever in built into the system.  note dual monitors work ok when I boot up in windows.

Comment: cornelius is asking "Which app do you use to control the monitor settings"?

Comment: When I'm running in windows The graphics are controlled by "intel Graphics Media Accelerator for Mobile". Is there an app for Ubuntu simular to this?  I hope this helps.